# Hide Controller name from url in codeigniter using routes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a url like this :

```
http://example.com/product/product_details/8
```

i want product_details to be hidden from url for that i used this routing rules:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'product';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['product/(:any)'] =  'product/product_details/$1';
```

then the url that appears in the browser is

> http://example.com/product/8

but the issue is that in the same controller i have called other controllers method for eg.  `public function addToCart(){  }` now when i call http://example.com/product/addToCart then it would not get called until i remove the above defined route. Please help to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have an ajax query for that. you need to remove the `<form>` tags. add id on your buttons like this: `<button class="approve" type="submit">Approve</button>`

then for your ajax query, change the url based on your route:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".approve").click(function(){
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $transactionCode = $row.find(".transactionCodeData").text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/method",
            data: { transactionKey: $transactionCode },
            success: function(data){
                location.reload(); //to refresh the browser
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks . I have implemented ajax query, but the problem arise when i use this url: http://example.com/product/addToCart , i want to know should i have to write rules for all methods in the product controller because i have many of them.

Comment: @user3653474 what is the problem?

Comment: I have 15 methods in my product controller should i have to define each method route in route.php or this can be also done with one line of code. I do not want to display controller name in my url.

Comment: @user3653474 you can do that in routes.php `$route['routename'] = 'controller/method;` then just call this routename using `redirect('routename')` after the successful query. you can just use one route depending on your needs.